# Class cast exception to same class on Android

Tags: android, classcastexception, findviewbyid

I'm having a strange problem with ClassCastException on Android. One class cannot be casted to the same class:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.model.BadeWrapper cannot be cast to com.example.model.BadgeWrapper

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.events.widgets.TouchyWebView cannot be cast to com.example.events.widgets.TouchyWebView

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.friends.widgets.FriendsTabView cannot be cast to com.example.friends.widgets.FriendsTabView
```

When I find the line with error, all it does is finding view by id or creating fragment with arguments e.g.:

```
FriendsTabView friendsTabView;
friendsTabView = (FriendsTabView) view.findViewById(R.id.friends_bottom_tab_panel);
```

As my BugSense tells, this problem occurs only on Samsung Galaxy S5 with android 5.0.0 (samsung SM-G900F). I have never met this problem on my other devices:

- Motorola Moto G 1st gen (Android 5.0.1)
- Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini (Android 4.1.2)
- LG G2 Mini (Android 4.4.2)
- Sony Xperia L (Android 4.1.2)

Anyone met this problem before? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the XML layout, the java class for the FriendsTabView (if available) and the java file where you use this FriendsTabView ?

Comment: Nevermind, problem is with Samsung Galaxy S5 device, see my answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok I where the problem is. Looks like Samsung on Android 5.0 probably still uses old implementation of multidex (used in Android L Preview), so if your app exceeds the 64k limit, it will crash in random places on your app where you use `(ExampleClass) object`  cast.

More info on this problem can be found [here](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/application-crushes-after-update-to-lollipop-on-samsung-galaxy-s5/202/278011?boardName=General&startId=zzzzz~) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=155376).

> We're also seeing this crash happen thousands of times per day.  Crashlytics reports the crash as 100% Samsung devices (99% "SM G900F[Q]" device), and 100% Android 5.x. Seems to be another multidex issue on Samsung + Lollipop devices, as a.jaskev reports in #3.

Looks like we have to wait until Samsung resolve this problem. Right now all we can do is watching our spam on mailbox with bug reports :)

Comment: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_norway_putting_android_5_for_galaxy_s5_and_s4_on_hold-news-11507.php

Now even Lolipop update is on hold due to this issue

Comment: Samsung: Not even once.