# class cast exception casting object to itself on android 5.0

Tags: android

There are a few variations of this issue but for this device I'm getting multiple reports of crashes

Model: samsung SM-G900F
Android: 5.0

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.Name[] cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.Name[]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.BytesToNameCanonicalizer.unshareNames(BytesToNameCanonicalizer.java:1033)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.BytesToNameCanonicalizer._addSymbol(BytesToNameCanonicalizer.java:808)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.BytesToNameCanonicalizer.addName(BytesToNameCanonicalizer.java:638)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.addName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2112)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.findName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1995)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseLongName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1607)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseMediumName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1576)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parseName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1512)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:701)
```

alternate stack trace with similar issue:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
at com.crowdcompass.bearing.client.eventdirectory.event.EventDirectoryFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(EventDirectoryFragment.java:418)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1868)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1989)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:276)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:599)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:973)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

I'm using proguard and have multidex enabled but it appears to be running fine on all other devices.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

build.gradle is pretty complex as we have quite a few dependencies.  here's the gist of it:

```
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    compileSdkVersion 19

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionName describeTag()
        versionCode initVersionCode()
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    dependencies {
        compile project (':ThirdParty:urbanairship-lib-5.1.4')
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
        compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
        compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6'
        compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.3.1@aar'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
        compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.0.8'
        compile 'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7R4'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.1'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.3.0'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.1'
    }
```

Comment: Post `build.gradle`.

Comment: Hmmm... are you doing anything odd with custom classloaders?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class

Comment: we're using the MultiDex library but I would expect a different type of error for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found someone with the same issue answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29008480/771677

Long story short Samsung devices are using an old implementation of multidex, leading to crashes on any device attempting to use that library.  I am irate.

> We're also seeing this crash happen thousands of times per day. Crashlytics reports the crash as 100% Samsung devices (99% "SM G900F[Q]" device), and 100% Android 5.x. Seems to be another multidex issue on Samsung + Lollipop devices, as a.jaskev reports in #3.