# Exception on serialization on Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: java, android

In my app I pass a data object from one `Activity` to another. The code is quite straightforward, on the first `Activity`:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BlablaActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Values.KEY_ITEM, item);
```

and on the receiving `Activity`:

```
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    item = (Item) intent.getSerializableExtra(Values.KEY_ITEM);
```

The `Advertising` class is very simple too:

```
public class Advertising implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7292860618498106953L;

    private Content content;
    private Anchor anchor;
    private String target;
    private String id;

// ...

}
```

And the `Anchor` class which seems to be causing this problem:

```
public class Anchor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7360857799761417956L;

    public String value;
    public String label;

// ...

}
```

I get the following exception only for the Samsung Galaxy S5 (sm-g900f):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field de.mycompany.model.Advertising.anchor 
>   has type de.mycompany.model.resultandexpose.Anchor, got
>   de.mycompany.model.resultandexpose.Anchor

and I can not make any sense of this, the expected class **is** the actual class. This seems to be yet another Samsung-specific problem. Anyone experienced this and knows a fix or has an idea what the cause for this is?

**EDIT:**

1. Yes, I am using Proguard. The proguard file looks like this:

   -keepattributes **
   -keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,** {*;}
   -dontpreverify
   -dontoptimize
   -dontshrink
   -dontwarn **

The second line is a workaround for a [known bug on Samsung devices](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=248142) and shouldn't touch any classes except those in the `android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.*` package.

- The serialVersionUID of the Anchor class is unique across all my classes.
- Switching to `Parcelable` would mean a massive overhaul of the whole project. Passing objects as `Serializable` *should* work on all devices.
- The `Anchor` class is just one example of this bug which happens on several other classes that basically look the same or very similar. So it isn't *that* one class but seems to be a more general problem.

Comment: What is `Content` ? Is it `Serializable`? Btw if you are not writing the object on file, switch to `Parcelable`.

Comment: @Blackbelt Content is pretty much analoge to Anchor and yes, it does implement Serializable.

Comment: Does `serialVersionUID` is unique for `Anchor`? Could it be that `Content` uses the same `serialVersionUID`?

Comment: Additionally, did you tried to put `Anchor`  to `Intent` extras directly (not as part another object)? Does it work?

Comment: Are you running proguard?

Comment: Edited the question to answer some some of your questions :)

Comment: Try `intent.setClassLoader(Anchor.class.getClassLoader())`. This sometimes helps with `Parcelable`, maybe this will help with `Serializable` as well.

Comment: Error message is misleading and not clear. It would make sense if you can follow up with Samsung at their developer forum: developer.samsung.com/forum

Comment: Have you ever regenerated the serialVersionUID at any point? I am curious if the class has been cached somewhere. Try doing a complete uninstall of the application if you haven't already and do a clean on your project.

Comment: Did you exceeded dex limit in your project? Are you using multidex?

Comment: @rwojcik Yes indeed I am using MultiDex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had simillar problem to yours,  and I found that with lolipop update on galaxy s5 devices samsung uses bugged multidex implementation. You can check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29007309/3266360) here explaining the problem. Someone answered to my question but I didn't checked if it works yet. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, although this doesn't solve the problem but at least I know I'm not alone :)
"Go to hell Samsung" for not even making an effort to explain the situation. 
Guess I'll have to tell our users that they bought a sh***y device.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Parcelable for passing object between two activities with intent.

You can look at [this tutorial](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/) that explain how it works, I suggest also to get a look at the Android Doc.